# Is there a European Journal of Cell Biology bibliography style?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, harvard-style

I have written a biology assignment in TeX, and am now struggling with making my bibliography match with the format we need to use for the course, that is, matching [this guide for authors](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/european-journal-of-cell-biology/0171-9335?generatepdf=true). We were told it is the Harvard style, but reading other questions on here I am realising that doesn't mean much.

I'm fairly new to LaTex so I don't know what to do to get my bibliography in this style. I'm using the biblatex package, and currently using the authoryear style, but it's not really the same.

[An example of the style in an article is here.](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/273240/1-s2.0-S0171933522X00022/1-s2.0-S0171933522000048/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEEcaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIHA6ATR%2BSY3ofF0%2BNY8NQ5109r%2FaihiCTd2gxB2Ip%2BIbAiEArn5vlOhSFs2snS%2Fy6NsFKBaM3EWVeivC03Z0HOLR8UwqgwQIsP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDHH%2F8Rf8u%2BNZMY5N6CrXA2CiTnoB2v3kAXOi4Vh%2FnpY291Ez6fAh1df5ipZBZ9ANbPpCxJh%2FC0axVTr6fIKjEr6UUO0O%2B7w24GYsLE715drk8OwTOnAPXNWx2%2BJIH7hfu6%2F0l%2B7eBcIHXlihwTQ5b%2F06iEBkGZmOJo9FyrT9idpZnmwJ0mJ%2FEZ9fOXjy5e5GRcNP7muzWpi6%2FiAfL6BlVc5n4AmMHjkajIOgW%2F7xpc%2Fgva8fZ4ADJxCLXtuYe6IwbExXrD%2BC6%2Fb80lrKFaSykpksJVWW7kmmUnXyR62c46pmiB9AGVvyCOwNoRejyA5vkeb1Ktm0aOBzTlAoKJPUIslLZl7wJzB1qJcOPFkGAJASpA9Eq%2FDnFEWtD6C4dhrLhZiKThN5Wp3%2FZWslvaU8%2F7HytdPNl%2BuNPz5nDx6fCczImWaOyAap1HKpYYppirjwK9Nd92z0bHHdUHr8E%2FB1dhy2wASH%2BX4BgG3bndcwnTIjeh4DIxAzTXgga8BPuRr6U7mqmtdEC3Jvvm%2F%2BEFKXCfGPX3bTrLQafe0cpLeACReYCyyZocEHHIh2vXzm3A75uwXl%2B1P%2B78XqKwY18rZI%2FMhv9ZObEYeeckh8TcCm2L8VR%2F3ZYuZLiuuZke7RGW91WA273Ed%2F%2FjCnnJqRBjqlATgsz7fYTUQ43zGpo3uu49jAt6hxGO6PKXDscVwNtftRKXPGW5T9fupV%2FMamS7y8E1p059VJpB80dOhRZuZL9vs61HP9Xor4PqZXR%2FerkmFER%2BS1h5r%2BHb893cnOYa8L8gSg5P9Du6OnH6C2m%2BLJrpKc3vm44G30aVRpNpFCvtseBImJO%2FlI%2FLBHA5Hv1yozy0kKvF7zwVVAWHjdmAy97KmzhXz%2Bsg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220307T234552Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYXOEU6GWA%2F20220307%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=46aba13614eed35b77627b7269d3fb9ee4375895a959aebe4a67fd679c37086f&hash=4b2a3fd5b31eb4e58cb0e5f5b8b23a1082a064c16ae431618f45914a5c785c2e&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0171933522000048&tid=spdf-0024e76b-c386-4725-b61f-3aaf2f2f4538&sid=115186bd915f574a777a4ed-b4f1559c384egxrqa&type=client&ua=4c0a5a5852525f065159&rr=6e87350d794c16a9)

Comment: Have you checked https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions?

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/a-simple-example-showing-how-to-create-harvard-style-referencing-in-latex/mnwzgkyvdbyy

Comment: You could start with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509

Comment: Chances are there is no ready-made `biblatex` style for this journal. Most journals/publishers don't accept `biblatex` in submissions. Often they encourage BibTeX-based or manual bibliographies. `biblatex` styles are a very rare exception. Elsevier specifically has a LaTeX template that comes with BibTeX bibliography styles. Those styles may or may not produce the same bibliography output found in published papers of that journal (sometimes there are discrepancies in the output that are fixed during the publishing process when the LaTeX source is postprocessed).

Comment: I guess your choice is to either use the template provided by the publisher and its BibTeX style and hope that it comes close to the desired output or to modify a standard `biblatex` style so that it does what you need (you can get started at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864, but for more specific issues you probably need to ask a new question if you can't find an existing one).

Answer (score 0):

I used `biblatex` (and its extension, see [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf)) to create what you need.

Maybe further refinements are needed (I only tested `article` and `book` as bib entries).

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bib.bib}
@article{andreadis1992structure,
  title={Structure and novel exons of the human. tau. gene},
  author={Andreadis, Athena and Brown, William M and Kosik, Kenneth S},
  journal={Biochemistry},
  volume={31},
  number={43},
  pages={10626--10633},
  year={1992},
  publisher={ACS Publications}
}
@article{baker2001electrostatics,
  title={Electrostatics of nanosystems: application to microtubules and the ribosome},
  author={Baker, Nathan A and Sept, David and Joseph, Simpson and Holst, Michael J and McCammon, J Andrew},
  journal={Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  volume={98},
  number={18},
  pages={10037--10041},
  year={2001},
  publisher={National Acad Sciences},
  url={https://the/url/of/the/article.com}
}
@article{desta2020performance,
  title={Performance and its limits in rigid body protein-protein docking},
  author={Desta, Israel T and Porter, Kathryn A and Xia, Bing and Kozakov, Dima and Vajda, Sandor},
  journal={Structure},
  volume={28},
  number={9},
  pages={1071--1081},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@book{laskowski2011ligplot+,
  title={LigPlot+: multiple ligand--protein interaction diagrams for drug discovery},
  author={Laskowski, Roman A and Swindells, Mark B},
  year={2011},
  publisher={ACS Publications}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    style=ext-authoryear,
    maxbibnames=99, 
    maxcitenames=2, 
    giveninits=true,
    uniquename=init,
    ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xurl}

% Citation settings
% comma between name and year in citations
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

% Bibliography settings
% Inversion of given and family names
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

%remove "and"  before the last name
\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

% remove parentheses around year and put a comma before it
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{\addcomma\addspace #1}

% no space between initials
\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{}

% titles without quotes
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}

% journal in normal font
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

% space between journal title
\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addspace}

% leave out "In:" before journal name
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct\nopunct}}}

% print only volume (no number)
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  }

% leave out "pp." from pages
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
    
% URL without the word "URL" and normal font
\urlstyle{same}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
% END Bibliography and citation customization

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
Autocite: \autocite{laskowski2011ligplot+}

Two citations \autocite{baker2001electrostatics, desta2020performance}

Cite: \cite{desta2020performance}

Parencite: \parencite{andreadis1992structure}

Textcite: \textcite{baker2001electrostatics}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]